# Make Workflow Context:Workflow Status URL use SSL connection

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, ssl

Is there a way to make the WorkflowContext:Workflow Status URL lookup use https instead of http?

Details:
My workflow sends off an email when action is required is needed to fill out a checklist. As the email goes out it's generating a checklist after information for the list has been filled out. In this scenario lets just say a new employee has started and they will need computer equipment and network access.

With in the email is a link that uses the lookup WorkflowContext:Workflow Status URL. The manager or tech clicks on this link, then clicks on Edit when they reach the URL, finally they fill out a checklist when items generated by the collect data action have been completed. However, I noticed that it will only use the servers name and will not use HTTPS to connect.

Server name is testserver
A Record is awesome.portal.com
SSL certificate is self-signed

I can navigate to https://awesome.portal.com, click around and will always see https including the workflow tasks lists.

Link to workflow within email goes to: http://testserver or comes up with an error if i have Require SSL checked in IIS for the web site.

I have setup Firefox, Internet Explorer and Chrome browsers to allow windows authentication so the "user" doesn't have to type in a password. However, it's just one of those questions I can't seem to find answer to yet.

Comment: you may be able to the utility actions to replace http with https if you bind the workflow url to a variable

Comment: Thank you, working this angle now. If I have any success I'll be sure to post it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
Replace 'http' with 'https' in WorkflowContext:Workflow Status URL(Output to Variable: WorkflowStatusUrlHTTPS)
```

Comment: Per your first suggestion and this one as well I went with the following:

Using SharePoint Workflow 2010 in Sharepoint Designer
Created Step named Extract Varaiable
Using 'Extract Substring from Start of String which read as
Copy 4 characters from start of WorkflowContext:WorkflowStatus URL (Output to Variable: varHTTPS)
then Set Variable: varHTTPS to https
then Log Variable conversion completed'

From here carried out the normal steps for sending email, collecting data and so forth. Confirmed that the link now uses https instead of http.

Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Glad to hear it @JkB !